# How do I connect a Cannon Pixma MG3550 printer wirelessly to my laptop?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, canon

It will not read the installation cd as its for windows, I have been on the cannon site but that is for windows or a mac.  I went into settings but need a url number for the printer(absolutely no idea)  Really hate ubuntu and sick of it now.  Can someone help me please.
No wire to connect it directly to printer

Answer (score 3):

Please see this site for details as to how to find the network information for your printer, under *Network settings confirmation*. http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/pixma_printer_wireless_connection_setup/mg3550_printer_wireless_connection_setup/

Next, using the Printer settings tool, use the URI of `ipp://<address>:631/lpr` where address is the IP address you found for the printer. For example, if the sheet the printer printed says the address of the printer is 192.168.1.8, the the URI you'd enter is: `ipp://192.168.1.8:631/lpr`.

Click 'Forward' and select Canon as the manufacturer. Scroll down to find 'Pixma MG3550`, select it and click 'Forward.' Print a test page.

Comment: +1 most pertinent search engine result and most straightforward way to a solution. @user445185: with your Pixma connected to yr WiFi network you can also detect its IP address (URI obtained thru Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol - DHCP) by reviewing yr router's IP address attributions. One way to do that is to get into yr router, presumably with administrator's  user name and password. In browser's locator field enter usual default router IP address 192.168.1.1 and proceed.

Comment: Thanks chili555, unfortunately I printed the sheet and it says Ip address disable I did try the MAC address but I got to the describe printer and it says CUPS server error.

Comment: You may need to connect the printer to the network first with a USB cable and another computer: http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/pixma_printer_wireless_connection_setup/mg3550_printer_wireless_connection_setup/#Tap2_back_to_top